# twitter API call 500 error

Tags: java, api, exception, twitter, urlconnection

how to handle the exception with URL connection when there is an "HTTP Error 500 Internal server" error from Twitter API .so how to handle it .i have coded this code in core java class and made a package for Twitter API call.

```
import java.net.*; 
import java.io.*;

public class getTwitterData {

    public static URLConnection connection;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Display the string.
            try {
            URLConnection connection = new URL("Twitter API call ").openConnection();
            InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
            System.out.println(response);

            }
        }catch(IOException ex) {}
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

response  will have http response code, and each response code can be handled differently if you want.

Comment: is it same like   ????                                                                             HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)connection;
InputStream is;
if (httpConn.getResponseCode() >= 400) {
    is = httpConn.getInputStream();
} else {
    is = httpConn.getErrorStream();
}